# Is this layout achievable with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I've been looking around at flex examples and having a go myself. I don't think this is possible with flexbox, but I thought I'd check before giving up on it.

The layout can be seen here:

[image]

All three elements are in the same parent div and unforntunately I'm stuck with this HTML structure so my options are limited. Sorry about the vague title. I couldn't really articulate the layout in words.

Thanks.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: @Paulie_D is right...there is a lot of ways to do what you want...one of them is flexbox..but first you must show us your code to help you

Comment: @Paulie_D I realise that this is a bit help vampire-y. It's just that it seemed a bit pointless taking the time to write an example of what I've tried when someone could easily tell me if it's not possible, or point me in the right direction. And if no one decided to answer me as a consequence, so be it. I'll be more detailed in the future though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since some kind soul has seen fit to answer...here's my version...no extra HTML required.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/vNZjrx)

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.box {
  width: 49.5%;
  background: #000;
}
.left {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  /* equals height */
  background: lightblue;
}
.right.top {
  flex: 0 0 39%;
  /* equals height */
}
.right.bottom {
  flex: 0 0 39%;
  /* equals height */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box left"></div>
  <div class="box right top"></div>
  <div class="box right bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: very nice, like how you are able to get the rows and columns all in 3 divs!

Answer (score 2):

As I'm trying to learn flex myself I thought I'd give this a go and came up with the following (otherwise this question should be closed for being too broad)

```css
.container {display:flex;}
.column {flex:1;}
.row {flex:1; background-color:black;}

#outer {flex-direction:row; height:250px;} /* height for example purpose only */
#left {background-color:black; margin-right:20px;}
#right {flex-direction:column;}
#top {margin-bottom:50px;}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="outer">
    <div class="column" id="left"></div>
    <div class="column container" id="right">
        <div class="row" id="top"></div>
        <div class="row" id="bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```